# Flutter call api rest with a long body

Tags: post, flutter, dart

When I call my rest API, I've an error :

```
I/flutter (25698): {user: {firstName: Jérémy, lastName: Gachon, pseudo: jerem, email: exemple@gmail.com, password: Abcd1234, birthDateDay: 24, birthDateMonth: 12, birthDateYear: 2004, language: fr}}
I/flutter (25698): gg1
I/flutter (25698): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

And here is my code :

```
Future<User> handleSignup(String email, String password, String pseudo,
  String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate) async {
var finalBirthDate = birthDate.split("/");
Map userDataFormated = {
  "user": {
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName,
    "pseudo": pseudo,
    "email": email,
    "password": password,
    "birthDateDay": finalBirthDate[0],
    "birthDateMonth": finalBirthDate[1],
    "birthDateYear": finalBirthDate[2],
    "language": 'fr'
  }
};
print(userDataFormated);
try {
  print("gg1");
  var res = await http.post(globals.apiUrl + "auth/createUser/", body: userDataFormated);
  print("gg2");
  print(res);
  if (res.statusCode == 201) {
    final map = convert.jsonDecode(res.body);
    final User user = new User.fromMap(map);
    return user;
  } else {
    print(res);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

The compiler does not accept when I put an map in the user in my body map.
Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

skip to Solution

### Problem

> _InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

### Step 1 : read http.post code

https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/master/lib/http.dart

```
Future<Response> post(url,
    {Map<String, String> headers, body, Encoding encoding})
```

### Step 2 : notice the comments

> [body] sets the body of the request. It can be a [String], a [List] or
>   a [Map]. If it's a String, it's encoded using [encoding] and
>   used as the body of the request. The content-type of the request will
>   default to "text/plain".

### Step 3 :

Map< string , Map < string,string > > is not equal map < string , string >

## Solution

#### import dart:convert

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
```

#### use convert.json.encode

```
body: convert.json.encode(userDataFormated)
```

Answer (score 0):

The soluce :

```
var res = await http.post(url, body: convert.json.encode(userDataFormated), headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"});
```